# Hours by Person

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, mosaic

Hello I can get to import my time column as a time format or date_time format It returns NA, how can i go about this, first_form should be time format and look like last_form(which is currently character) on the preview
?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o8KN.png)

```
Inmigrations <- read_excel("Inmigrations.xlsx", 
    col_types = c("skip", "skip", "skip", 
        "skip", "text", "date", "text", "text", 
        "numeric", "text", "numeric", "date"))
```

Comment: Try importing it as a character and converting it inside R. We don't have access to your Excel file, so it is very difficult to debug for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try lubridate after importing it as character type:

```
library(lubridate)

df$first_form <- hms(df$first_form)
```